# How to set the list of features which will be installed if the button was pushed?

Tags: wix

I'am using `WixUI_Mondo` set. I modified "CompleteButton" button in the `SetupTypeDlg`:

```
<Control Id="ServerButton" Type="PushButton" X="40" Y="120" Width="80" Height="17" ToolTip="!(loc.SetupTypeDlgServerButtonTooltip)" Text="!(loc.SetupTypeDlgServerButton)">
   <Publish Property="WixUI_InstallMode" Value="InstallServer">1</Publish>                  
   <Publish Property="SERVICE" Value="[SERVSTR]">1</Publish>
   <Publish Property="ADDLOCAL" Value="Feature1,Feature2,Feature3">1</Publish>
</Control>

<Property Id="ADDLOCAL" Secure="yes"></Property>
```

When I push `ServerButton` the log says:

```
(CLIENT)     MSI (c) (1C:88) [15:28:49:154]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ADDLOCAL property. Its value is 'Feature1,Feature2,Feature3'. 
(UNKNOWN)     Действие 15:28:49: ServStrDlg. Dialog created 
(UNKNOWN)     Действие 15:28:53: ShortsDlg. Dialog created 
(UNKNOWN)     Действие 15:28:55: VerifyReadyDlg. Dialog created 
(CLIENT)     MSI (c) (1C:88) [15:28:55:966]: Note: 1: 2727 2: 
(UNKNOWN)     Действие закончено 15:28:56: WelcomeDlg. Код возврата 1. 
(CLIENT)     MSI (c) (1C:DC) [15:28:56:076]: Doing action: ProgressDlg 
(UNKNOWN)     Действие 15:28:56: ProgressDlg. 
(UNKNOWN)     Начало действия 15:28:56: ProgressDlg. 
(UNKNOWN)     Действие 15:28:56: ProgressDlg. Dialog created 
(UNKNOWN)     Действие закончено 15:28:56: ProgressDlg. Код возврата 1. 
(CLIENT)     MSI (c) (1C:DC) [15:28:56:091]: Doing action: ExecuteAction 
(UNKNOWN)     Действие 15:28:56: ExecuteAction. 
(UNKNOWN)     Начало действия 15:28:56: ExecuteAction. 
(CLIENT)     MSI (c) (1C:DC) [15:28:56:091]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SECONDSEQUENCE property. Its value is '1'. 
(CLIENT)     MSI (c) (1C:DC) [15:28:56:091]: Grabbed execution mutex. 
(CLIENT)     MSI (c) (1C:DC) [15:28:56:091]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0 
(CLIENT)     MSI (c) (1C:DC) [15:28:56:091]: Switching to server: NETFRAMEWORK40CLIENT="#1"INSTALLLOCATION="some dir" TARGETDIR="C:\"
 MANUFACTURERDIR="C:\Program Files\..\" CURRENTDIRECTORY="C:\.." CLIENTUILEVEL="0" CLIENTPROCESSID="6684" USERNAME="User" COMPANYNAME=".."
 SOURCEDIR=".." ACTION="INSTALL" EXECUTEACTION="INSTALL" SECONDSEQUENCE="1" ROOTDRIVE="C:\" INSTALLLEVEL="1" ADDLOCAL=Feature4,Feature5,Feature6
```

Levels of Feature1,Feature2,Feature3 are more than 3. Can't figure out why it's passing `INSTALLLEVEL="1"`.

**UPD:**

I made next changes, the result is same. The installer is modifying values of INSTALLLEVEL,ADDLOCAL properties on client-side. On server-side: INSTALLLEVEL=11,ADDLOCAL consists of features with "Level" attribute<=11.

```
<Control Id="ServerButton" Type="PushButton" X="40" Y="120" Width="80" Height="17" ToolTip="!(loc.SetupTypeDlgServerButtonTooltip)" Text="!(loc.SetupTypeDlgServerButton)">
   <Publish Property="WixUI_InstallMode" Value="InstallServer">1</Publish> 
   <Publish Event="SetInstallLevel" Value="11">1</Publish>                 
   <Publish Property="SERVICE" Value="[SERVSTR]">1</Publish>
   <Publish Property="ADDLOCAL" Value="Feature1,Feature2,Feature3">1</Publish>
</Control>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I read this [article](http://www.joyofsetup.com/2007/05/30/feature-conditions-and-ui/) many times and finally found: i have to publish `Event='AddLocal'` not a `Property`. **Thank's, Yan, for your time very much.** Here is working code:

```
<Control Id="ServerButton" Type="PushButton" X="40" Y="120" Width="80" Height="17" ToolTip="!(loc.SetupTypeDlgServerButtonTooltip)" Text="!(loc.SetupTypeDlgServerButton)">
   <Publish Property="WixUI_InstallMode" Value="InstallServer">1</Publish>                  
   <Publish Property="SERVICE" Value="[SERVSTR]">1</Publish>
   <Publish Event="AddLocal" Value="ALL">1</Publish>
   <Publish Event="Remove" Value="Feature4">1</Publish>
   <Publish Event="Remove" Value="Feature5">1</Publish> 
   <Publish Event="Remove" Value="Feature6">1</Publish>
</Control>
```

And I added an event to the "Back" button of the next dialog:

```
<Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="192" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUIBack)">
   <Publish Event="SetInstallLevel" Value="3">WixUI_InstallMode="InstallServer"</Publish>
</Control>
```

Comment: It's great you've found it out finally!

Answer (score 4):

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369536.aspx), the installation level specified by the `INSTALLLEVEL` property can be overridden by a number of properties, including `ADDLOCAL`. Hence, as far as I understand it, even if `INSTALLLEVEL` is set to `1`, it gets overriden by the `ADDLOCAL` property and is not taken into consideration by the Windows Installer.

If you experience any error or wrong behavior related to this, add more details about it to your question.

Comment: I found the related article from Bob here: http://www.joyofsetup.com/2007/05/30/feature-conditions-and-ui/. I'm doing the same as described in. Or not? The log doesn't indicate any error. According the log-file,installer sets ADDLOCAL="Feature1,Feature2,Feature3" as is required. May be it is too late to set this property..Can't understand

Comment: No error in the log, but what about the behavior? Is it what you expected or not?

Comment: No,it installs features with INSTALLLEVEL=1 - it uses the default value. i don't set it anywhere. I expect that it will use the new value of ADDLOCAL property. But it doesn't

Comment: The original `CompleteButton` publishes the event `SetInstallLevel`, which sets the `INSTALLLEVEL` to `1000`: `<Publish Event="SetInstallLevel" Value="1000">1</Publish>`  Are you missing this in your changes `CompleteButton` control?

Comment: Yes, I had deleted this row. I have no SetInstallLevel action inside my control element

Comment: Well, I think you have to have it. This is how I understand it works. Suppose you have 3 features, with levels set to `100`, `200` and `300` appropriately. If you set `INSTALLLEVEL` to `300`, it will install all 3 features, but if you additionally set `ADDLOCAL` to `Feature1,Feature2`, it will only install first 2, meaning the `INSTALLLEVEL` is still 300. You can try it out actually: return the `SetInstallEvent` back and let it set `INSTALLLEVEL` to the biggest level of the features you'd like to install, and then set `ADDLOCAL` to exact subset you want.

Comment: See this article (the very bottom of the page): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368585.aspx

Comment: I had updated the question.I want to install feature with level=10,and not to install features with level=1.I broke my mind

Comment: Windows Installer will install the features less or equal to the current `INSTALLLEVEL`. If you need the opposite behavior, just revise the Level values on your features.

Comment: I know, but according to doc AddLocal must override InstallLevel property. I can't use conditions in feature table, because during UI is showing,they had been already evaluated. I have mutually exclusive
 features that's why I can't use SetInstalllevel Property.For example,i have several features with level=1.And two features like: Feature1 with level=2 ; Feature2 with level=5. Then if i want to install features with level=1 and Feature2,what should I do?If I'll set InstallLevel=5 then Feature1 will be also installed. But it's not what i want. That's why I'm trying to use AddLocal

Comment: Exactly i want to have two buttons on this Dialog: ClientButton and ServerButton.On the ClientButton I use SetInstallLevel. But i can't do it on ServerButton.Because the level of server-feature is more than level of client-feature.