# Condition inside Feature ignores property value that is set in custom action

Tags: wix

I have a feature that I want to be selected or deselected according to a property value:

```
<Feature Id="featHAService" Title="!(loc.HAService)" AllowAdvertise="no" Level="1">
  <Condition Level="3">
    <![CDATA[PROP_IS_FIRST_INSTALLATION="0"]]>
  </Condition>
</Feature>
```

In the C# custom action, before showing CustomizeSetup dialog that contains features tree, I set the PROP_IS_FIRST_INSTALLATION according to some logic and no matter if the value is 0 or 1 the Feature Level is always 1. For debug purposes I stopped triggering the custom action and manually changed the value of PROP_IS_FIRST_INSTALLATION int the *.wxs file, and condition works as expected. Any idea why changing it in custom action does not work?

Comment: Have you checked the install log files?  Is the custom action invoked before the feature selection?  The log file should indicate the sequence and values of all property changes.

Comment: Yes, the value of the property is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the sequence order in which these calls happen, because the conditions in features are evaluated during the CostFinalize action, so your custom action must be before CostFinalize.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368014(v=vs.85).aspx

It's more usual in my opinion to have a DoAction controlEvent in these cases. The dialog event can do an ADDLOCAL on the required feature and a remove on the other. The custom action can then be triggered by the feature condition on the feature being installed, such as &FeatureName=3. There is an example here:

[How to set the list of features which will be installed if the button was pushed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738695/how-to-set-the-list-of-features-which-will-be-installed-if-the-button-was-pushed)

Comment: Actually, it is happens not in sequential custom action but in transition between dialogs. There is a custom action that being fired at button click and in that custom action there is a logic if feature should be level 1 or 3

Comment: If it's after CostFinalize, there's the problem.